# Gestion de projet

Tags: usage

J'ai rencontré la tournure

> gestion de projet

et les deux variantes

> gestion de projet personnel
>
> gestion de projet recherche

Je me demande si cette dernière-ci est correcte ou pas.
En effet, n'est-il pas plus correct de dire

> gestion de projet **de** recherche

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oui, *personnel* est un adjectif mais *recherche* est un substantif donc :

> Gestion de projet(s) de recherche.